# How do I set the color or transparency of the isolated?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have isolated some elements in this image, but the isolated elements are hard to see in this background, how can I set the color or transparency of the isolated elements? Thanks
[Here's what it looks like in the background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/envY1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setThemingColor` can help you to identify ghost objects. But the transparency is still active.

Something like this :
`viewer.setThemingColor(<dbid>, new THREE.Vector4(1, 0, 0, 1), model, true)` will color a ghost object in red.

[image: Color ghost object]

Then you can use `viewer.clearThemingColors(model)` to remove the colors.

Comment: Thanks, I also used this method to set the color of the isolated object and it was useful

Answer (score 0):

Use [getIsolatedNodes](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v4/reference/javascript/viewer3d/#getisolatednodes) to get an array of the IDs of the currently isolated nodes.

Then we can operate them like:

```
_viewer.setColorMaterial(_viewer.getIsolatedNodes(),0xff0000);
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't find the method setColorMaterial